# Python 3.6.3 pyautogui.locateOnScreen not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I have a "find.png" (attached)
The pyautogui.locateOnScreen is returning None, even after 20 screenshots!!!!
Using interpreter (code attached)
Note: 1) the image having the line, "import pyautogui as auto", is "find.png"
2)I have "find.png" in the same directory, it is founded( checked with PIL- Image)
[image: pic contains the line, "import pyautogui as auto"]
[image: code which is returning, "None"]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After struggling with this forever also, finally figured out that you either use command line or print screen button with the windows key to take the screenshot. Using the snipping tool does not work
so try:

```
image = pyautogui.screenshot()
image.save('testing.png')
```

Go and crop testing.png as small as possible so that locateOnScreen works faster. Then go back to the terminal and type:

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('testing.png')
```

Comment: Why so late? Hope it helps

Comment: Tried it. It's working!!!. Successfully detected the coords of "pyautogui". Thanks a lot, I used the pyautogui.screenshot() method

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('testing.png', confidence =.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

None simply means that PyAutoGui was unable to find your image on the screen, do remember the window is active where find.png was sampled from. 
If this doesn't work out then I believe the resolutions(from when you took the sample and the monitor used by you) are different.
Let us know if you face any problem.

Comment: Yes it was active. I have tried multiple ways, including active while taking screenshots and active while locating. Monitors are Same,

Comment: As per the PyAutoGui documentation the other problem for failure could be the resolutions of monitors as I wrote. Did you checked on some other files.

Comment: Yes, Checked with the "PC" icon, calculator button, not working

Comment: @Susmit: Also one query whether there is any animation in images too.

Comment: No simple image, screenshot and then crop, also tried using snipping tool to take screenshots of particular region.

Comment: Well I'll try it on my machine and get back to you. But it may take a while till such you can go through the bug mention for this issue on below link :
https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/4

Comment: Checked on my machine everything is as expected. Your code ran as expected without any errors. So this could be among one of the problems mentioned on link which I shared in previous comment.