# Python 2.7 Pyautogui.locateOnScreen not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

For some unknown reason the Pyautogui's `locateOnScreen()` function (and all other Pyautogui's locate functions) is not working properly and returns `None`.

---

**My Code:**

```
>>> pyautogui.screenshot('test.png',region=(100,20, 30, 20))
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=30x20 at 0x39E35C0>
>>> print pyautogui.locateOnScreen('test.png')
None
```

---

**My research**

I know that when it returns `None`, it means that `pyautogui` was *not able to locate* the image on the screen. I also know that it has to be *visible* on the screen. The code above was executed while *not moving a single window*.

I also know that there are very similar/identical questions at stackoverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709009/python-3-6-3-pyautogui-locateonscreen-not-working). But the solution from that question is not applicable to my situation since I am actually using the *pyautogui's screenshot and cropping features* straightaway and not even cropping with 3rd party software, yet pyautogui is not able to locate it.

---

**Additional info**

Python: `2.7.15 (64-bit)`

OS: `Windows 10 Home 64-bit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`locateOnScreen`, `locateCenterOnScreen` and (probably) all other Pyautogui's *locate* functions have an optional argument `confidence`.

As the name implies, set how much Pyautogui can **tolerate slight deviations**. Decreasing the confidence value down *solve this issue* but increase the chance of *false positives*.

Side-note: `confidence` is not mentioned in [Pyautogui's documentation](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io). It would be great and very helpful if they would add it in there.